# Java Sound microphone reconnection

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Is it possible to identify if a microphone has been physically unplugged and replugged using the java Sound API?

More specifically, if I have an open line and the microphone is disconnected and reconnected the list returned by `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` does not change and the line remains open but recording stops. Is there a way to find out about such disconnect/reconnect events (without using native calls) ?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2105421/Java-Sound-Capturing-Microphone-Data-into-an-Audio-File.htm

Comment: Good introduction but does not help. The reason for the list not changing between calls to `getMixerInfo` is that the `JDK13Services` class caches the list of devices that are returned by `getMixerInfo`

Comment: @msam I had the same problem and also used the JDK13Services for detecting a microphone, but I am still not able to use its Lines. Did you succeed in doing so? Please comment or answer to my question if you have a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874713/java-sound-refresh-lines-list-after-attaching-a-microphone . Thanks.